# Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in dbunit\PHPUnit\Extensions\Database\TestCase.php on line 24

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, dbunit

I want to write tests for MySQL Database. When I try to extend the database extension, it gives me the above error in title:

```
class FixtureTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
```

Note: I have installed `PHPUnit` globally and I can access it through phpunit in cmd. I have latest `PHPUnit` 4.5.1.

I also installed `Dbunit` globally through `composer`:

```
composer global require phpunit/dbunit
```

Any help will be much appreciated. I've used PHP 5.4.

Comment: Have you tried with  `\` ` before? as:   `class FixtureTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase`

Comment: Hi have you find a solutions?

Comment: Path of autoload.php  might create a problem. It depends on the installation of composer. I'd recommend you check inside the composer. From there you can provide path for vendor/autoload.php. Composer can be a hidden folder. So you'll have to look for it.

Answer (score 3):

For referring to classes that are located within the global namespace, you can simply prefix them with a backward ( \ ) slash.
Try with this:

```
class FixtureTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
```

With the leading backward ( \ ) slash, PHP knows that we are referring to the `PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase` class in the global namespace, and located that one.

More info [here](http://daylerees.com/php-namespaces-explained)

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

It just might be the version of DBUnit. For example I'm using `PHPUnit 4.8` and it works with `DBUnit 1.4`.

I had the above error when I was using composer with `"phpunit/dbunit": ">=1.2"` and I ended up with DBUnit 2.0.

Answer (score -3):

Test your DB how? Through an API you created or direct accesses to DB? i would recommend you to write an API to access your DB and then write the tests to the API.
for exemple if you want to insert a user you call your web-server address (localhost:3000) or something you have and then call /users through POST to insert and make the routes to that.
I would suggest using LARAVEL for that.

Comment: @Pedora dbunit is an extension of PHPUnit which is used for testing the Database transactions or CRUD. We don't have to create any API or to use Laravel. Checkout this URL.  [PHPUnit Database testing](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html)

Comment: Yeah i know you dont have to create an API i just asked and but it is as hard to use it directly or create an API and consume it and its easier

Comment: I think this is quite common to use PHPUnit for testing. So I think its better to understand it rather than to create an API or use Laravel as you had suggested.